# API GET REQUEST - UDF Fields

Tags: java, api, rest

I'm trying to pull data from a user-defined field.

When pulling from system define fields it is working but when I try to pull from the UDF fields it's not working.

[screenshot of the record I'm trying to pull](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7Vsz.png)

Pulling using Id 374 is working but I cannot pull using the CRM case ID.

[working API ID 374](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGGJj.png)
[non working API CRM Case ID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7wIX.png)

any help with this would be much appreciated.
I am using postman to do this calls.

thank you.

Comment: Can you add more details please? What is the API that you're working with?

Comment: @TimMoore please see my screenshot links.

Comment: I saw the screenshot, but they don't tell me what API this question is about. I saw the question because it's tagged with [java], but the question isn't about Java. The [api] and [rest] tags are too general. If you want someone who might be able to answer this question to see it, it needs to have appropriate tags and more details added. Otherwise, it's likely to be closed.